# MultiChoiceMode before API 11

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i implement the ActionMode in my Android App with ActionBarSherlock.
With ABS it is possible to build a ActionMode before API 11 but the easy way with:
`listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener( new MultiChoiceModeListener() ...`
is not for app before API 11.
Has anybody a good way to build a Action Mode Context Menu before API 11?
I want to make a long click on a List Item and start the ActionMode in which i can click multiple items. On a simple click i show a detail site of the list item.
I use the `registerForContext()` method but this make a simple and long click.

Has anybody a good tip for me.

**EDIT**
The solution for my question was following: On a long item click i active the action mode and save this in a variable. In the on item click method i implement a if-else statement with:

```
if( actionMode == null )
{
   // open new activity or update second fragment
   showDetails( itemPosition );
}
else
{
   // update ui or close CAB if no item selected
   showCAB( itemPosition );
}
```

The method showCAB( position ) update the selectedItem count, highlight item background and so on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alright, I just did that today, thanks to that site : http://www.miximum.fr/tutos/849-porting-the-contextual-anction-mode-for-pre-honeycomb-android-apps

Basically, you just need to set your ListView ChoiceMode to `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`, to set a `onItemClickListener` that would check what items are checked on the ListView and to create a private class implementing `ActionMode.Callback` that will manage the contextual ActionBar.

I let you go on that blogpost to see everything detailed, and some piece of codes !

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found this page also yesterday and implement the solution. I change the onItemClickListener to a onItemLongClickListener and this runs not so good. I can start the ActionMode after a short click on one Item, close my activity which opens up and then press long again on the item. The solution is not perfect but good for the start.

Comment: If I understand well your problem, it's that it stills open your activity on a simple click on your ListView's items ? Then, on your `onItemLongClickListener`, you can set the `listView` `onItemClickListener` to null, so that it doesn't open any activity. Be sure to set it back to the original `onItemClickListener` (you can save it in a variable) on the `onDestroyActionMode` of the `ModeCallback` class

Comment: Before the onItemClick method is called the event passed the onItemLongClick method. This method return a boolean so if i return true the event was handled and didn't reach the onItemClick method. If i return false i didn't handle the long click and make a other type of click. I found this in some other questions but your solution is also possible. I test it a little bit later today.

Comment: Yeah, what I said was that if you want to have the ability to simple click on the items to select them (after the first long click), you need to remove the onItemClickListener from your ListView, so that it doesn't trigger the launching activity event. But yeah, you also have to return true with the `onItemLongClick` to consume the event, and not trigger the simple click when you want to do a long click

Answer (score 5):

You can also have a look at the [Google I/O 2012 App](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/). It's opensource, and uses ActionBarSherlock. They have developed a compatibility version of **ActionMode** related classes that work fine with ABS and on pre-honeycomb devices.

In particular, Take a look at:

- [SessionsFragment](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/SessionsFragment.java) class : It shows usage of the compatibility version of ActionMode
- [util.actionmodecompat](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/#git/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/actionmodecompat%253Fstate%253Dclosed) package: It contains the compatibility ActionMode
  classes

Basically, just like ABS, their use native implementation of ActionMode when it is available and fallback to the custom implementation on older devices.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your info is really helpful, thanks. I found this file is helpful too when using ActionMode and ActionBarActivity from appcompat v7 package. http://iosched.googlecode.com/git/android/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/MultiSelectionUtil.java