# How to use multiselect in GridView with custom adapter?

Tags: android, gridview

I have the `GridView` with `ImageView` and `TextView` in every cell. That worked fine and have no problems. But I need multichoice in this `GridView`. I want that the selected cells will be gray and unselected cells must be white. I've try to make selector with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/item_unselected" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected" />
</selector>
```

and set `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"` in my `GridView`, but it doesn't work. How I can to do that?

Comment: [check this library](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/multichoiceadapter/) may be it help you.

Answer (score 4):

look at that [ThisdemoillustratestheuseofCHOICEMODEMULTIPLEMODALakaselectionmodeonGridView](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/ThisdemoillustratestheuseofCHOICEMODEMULTIPLEMODALakaselectionmodeonGridView.htm)

Comment: Thank you! But setMultiChoiceModeListener require API version 11 and I need 5. Is there another way to resolve it?

Comment: Look at that please , maybe it can help to you ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590640/multichoicemode-before-api-11

Comment: Thank's for your answers, I will try this.